# CastleWindsor. BuildDatabaseConfiguration & Kernel

Tags: .net, nhibernate, kernel, castle-windsor

Good day! 
I guided some manual for use CastleWindsor. [This manual here.](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Six-Persistence-Layer.ashx) But I don't understand, how to use (or where to use) this:

```
var config = BuildDatabaseConfiguration();

Kernel.Register(
    Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(_ => config.BuildSessionFactory()),
    Component.For<ISession>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()));
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a configuration needed when you use NHibernate but it's what you can already read in the manual.

The piece of code you're showing comes from `PersistenceFacility` class that you can see here : https://github.com/kkozmic/ToBeSeen/blob/master/src/ToBeSeen/Plumbing/PersistenceFacility.cs

`PersistenceFacility` class is configured within the Windsor Installer which is here : https://github.com/kkozmic/ToBeSeen/blob/master/src/ToBeSeen/Installers/PersistenceInstaller.cs

Take a look on the whole project here : https://github.com/kkozmic/ToBeSeen